# sql query with current day comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with a due_date field which is simply an integer value.

```
dealID   |  due_day
1        |   15
2        |   25
3        |   10
4        |    9
5        |   31
6        |   20
```

I would like to query this table to only display the data that would be 14 days before the due_day. For example, today is 01/05/13, if I query this table it should only show me dealID 1, 3 and 9. How should I go about this condition?

Comment: What database are you using?  (MySQL/SQL Server/Oracle/...)

Comment: You probably meant 1,3 and 4 (no id 9 in the example)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on user1951544's answer this is what I came up with.

```
    SELECT due_day
    FROM deals
    WHERE (due_day - DAYOFMONTH( NOW( ) ) ) <=14
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that simply using [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) to substract the number of days from current date and then [DAYOFMONTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth) to get the day.

You can create the query using the mentioned functions.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b794/7)**

```
SELECT 
dealID, 
due_day
FROM Table1
WHERE due_day  < 14 + DAYOFMONTH( NOW( ) )
```

Result:

```
| DEALID | DUE_DAY |
--------------------
|      1 |      15 |
|      3 |      10 |
|      4 |       9 |
```